# Component controller and Main VF page Controller Data Pass

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have VF Component controller class that extends the Main VF page Controller class. The component is added inside the Main VF page.  I am not able to pass the input field from component to main Controller. When I insert, only main VF page input field is inserted, not the component input field. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Insert method is inserting a "insert ListofCandidate(Candidate)" , Candidate Object have some filed in the Component and some input filed in the VF page.

Comment: Please add some code to the question.  Without that, we can only guess.